# Update the _style.scss file in 2sxc content

Tags: sass, 2sxc

I'm creating a new content type for 2sxc content and I'm trying to include some styling.

1. am I correct in assuming I add any custom css to 'src > styles > _styles.css'
2. if so, how do I update the package?

sorry for the newbie question and TIA

Regards
Martyn C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes, it's all SASS based. You should simply run `npm ci` in the root to restore all npm packages which are used for sass. Webpack should then take care of the building and all that :)

I suggest you have a look an the `package.json` where everything should be explained.